# Using Liquibase extensions with Maven

Tags: maven, liquibase

I am trying to use [Liquibase Oracle extensions](http://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/Oracle+Extensions) from [maven-liquibase-plugin](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/maven) but I'm not able to get it working. I have no issue with the same changeLog file from the command line, but in Maven I get the following error message

```
SEVERE 21/11/11 14:49:liquibase: Error thrown as a SAXException: Unknown Liquibase extension: dropTrigger. Are you missing a jar from your classpath?
```

The changelog file I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ora="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
    <changeSet author="PE1926" id="ONCHANGE" runOnChange="true">
    <ora:dropTrigger schemaName="" triggerName="TRIGGER_01"/>
    <rollback>
        <sqlFile path="latest/trg/TRIGGER_01.sql" endDelimiter="$"/>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

Here is a pom.xml extract

```
[...]
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-oracle</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>       
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals><goal>status</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/update.xml</changeLogFile>    
                <propertyFile>${db-resources.dir}/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I've also tried to add liquibase-oracle as plugin dependency but I get the same error message.

Is this the correct way of using Liquibase extensions from Maven? Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not a Liquibase user however to express a plugin's dependency you have add a `dependencies` section **within** the `plugin` element.

Comment: As stated I tried adding liquibase-oracle as a plugin dependency with no luck. However, I've tried adding all of them as plugin dependencies and it seems to work. Would you write an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add all liquibase dependencies as **plugin dependencies**.

Comment: Stupidly simple... I should have figured it out but it's late and I've had too much coffee. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need to add any other dependencies - this did it for me:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.liquibase}</version>
    <configuration>
      <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
      <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
      <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
      <changeLogFile>liquibase-master-changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
      <!-- ensure a liquibase.properties is available in each module that runs liquibase -->
      <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-oracle</artifactId>
        <version>${version.liquibase.ora-ext}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>test-compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>update</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: You added all liquibase dependencies as plugin dependencies. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8215645/33622